# A Propriedade box-shadow: inset não funciona na tag<img>

Tags: html, css, css3, imagem, webdesign

Eu estava testando a propriedade `box-shadow` para fazer uma galeria e percebi que a tag `<img>` não aceita o `box-shadow:inset...` porém aceita o `box-shadow` normal.

No entanto se eu colocar a `<img>` como background de uma `div` o `box-shadow:inset` funciona direitinho!

*Minha dúvida seria:* Como colocar o box-shadow:inset sem ter que usar a imagem como background?

Modelo simples para exemplificar

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 20px;
}
div { 
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 40px 0;
    background-image: url(//www.fillmurray.com/200/200);
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 10px red, 0 0 5px 10px #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 10px red, 0 0 5px 10px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 10px red, 0 0 5px 10px #000000;
}
img.bs {
    display: block;
    margin: 40px 0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 10px red, 0 0 5px 10px #000000;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 10px red, 0 0 5px 10px #000000;
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 10px red, 0 0 5px 10px #000000;
}
img.ds {
    filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 10px red);
    -webkit-filter: drop-shadow(0px 0px 10px red);
}
```

```html
<div></div>
<img class="bs" src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWdCL.png' alt='' height="200"/>
<img class="ds" src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWdCL.png' alt=''/>
```

OBS: também tentei com a propriedade `filter:drop-shadow` mas ela não tem a opção de `inset`

Answer (score 1):

Acho que identifiquei o problema sobre o fato do `box-shadow:inset` não funciona na `<img>` e resumidamente se deve ao fato da imagem ser um elemento do tipo `Replaced element`

Veja o que a documentação da Mozilla diz sobre os **Replaced element**

> In CSS, a replaced element is an element whose representation is outside the scope of CSS; they're external objects whose representation is independent of the CSS formatting model.

Tradução: *"Em CSS, um elemento substituído é um elemento cuja representação está fora do escopo do CSS; eles são objetos externos cuja representação é independente do modelo de formatação CSS."*

*Fonte:* https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/CSS/Replaced_element

**A W3C fala que:**

> For example, the content of the HTML IMG element is often replaced by the image that its "src" attribute designates. ... The content of replaced elements is not considered in the CSS rendering model.

Tradução: *"Por exemplo, o conteúdo do elemento HTML IMG é frequentemente substituído pela imagem que seu atributo "src" designa. ... O conteúdo dos elementos substituídos não é considerado no modelo de renderização CSS.*

*Fonte:* https://www.w3.org/TR/CSS21/conform.html#replaced-element

Talvez por isso a renderização da imagem fique por cima do `box-shadow:inset` já que o controle do conteúdo da imagem *(src)* não é definido pelo CSS.

Repare que nesse código eu fiz um experiência usando a propriedade `object-fit` e `object-position` para deslocar a imagem dentro do próprio "*container*". Repare que a sombra está lá, mas ela fica por baixo do conteúdo da imagem *(src)*

```css
img {
    -webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 10px red;
    -moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 10px red;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 10px 10px red;
    object-fit: contain;
    object-position: top 25px left 25px;
    border: 1px solid;
}
```

```html
<img src='https://i.stack.imgur.com/oWdCL.png' alt=''/>
```

**OBS:** No Chrome e Firefox é possível ver o teste, mas certifique-se que o seu browser suporta `object-fit`: https://caniuse.com/#feat=object-fit

Comment: Uma sugestão, se usar um PNG transparente poderá perceber sem precisar do `object-position`. Se me permitir gostaria de trocar o link da w3 por esse: https://html.spec.whatwg.org/multipage/rendering.html#replaced-elements

Comment: @GuilhermeNascimento claro Guilherme, é um favor que vc faz para a comunidade manter as coisas atualizadas dentro do possível. Agradeço pela colaboração, e fique a vontade para editar qq resposta minha, abs :)

Answer (score -1):

Olá! Pelo que pesquisei, não é possível aplicar box-shadow:inset em uma tag img. Porém, umsa solução que encontrei foi criar um container vazio e adicionar a imagem como background.

HTML:

```
<div class="container-img"></div>
```

CSS:

```
.container-img {

background-image: url('caminho da imagem');
background-position: center;
background-size: 100%; /* Ajustar */
/* Box shadow: */
-webkit-box-shadow: inset 0 0 11.5px 10px #000000;
-moz-box-shadow: inset 0 0 11.5px 10px #000000;
box-shadow: inset 0 0 11.5px 10px #000000; }
```

Comment: Sua resposta pode ser melhorada adicionando informações fundamentais. Basta [edit] para adicionar mais detalhes, como citações ou documentação para que outras pessoas possam confirmar que sua resposta está correta. Você pode encontrar mais informações sobre como escrever boas respostas [na Central de Ajuda](/help/how-to-answer).

Answer (score -3):

```css
html, body {
    height: 100%;
    width: 100%;
    margin: 20px;
}
img {
    width: 200px;
    height: 200px;
    margin: 40px 0;
    box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 #000000, 0 0 10px 7px red, -1px 0px 7px 20px #000000;
}
```

```html
<img src='//www.fillmurray.com/200/200' alt=''/>
```

Comment: O estilo que vc colocou está zerado... `box-shadow: inset 0 0 0 0 #000000` e a sombra tem que estar por cima da imagem e não para fora da imagem.